# Is it possible to refill my reservoir manually?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I've been exploring and using my trusty fuel scoop to fill up my main tank.

However it's annoying when my reservoir is low that this isn't filled. Is there a way to trigger a refill or the reservoir (other than flying aimlessly)?

Answer (score 3):

Other than docking at a station and buying fuel, there is no way to refill your  Main Tank. Do not worry, though. When the tank depletes, it will pull from the Reservoir FTL tank (1 or 2 tons) without any interruptions.

FTL jumps use your reservoir, and everything else uses your main tank. Fuel scooping at stars only fills your reservoir.

Comment: Your answer is correct, however "don't worry" does not always apply. If you fly smaller ships with small fuel tanks the amount of fuel taken from your main tank for the reservoir can be pretty huge. It took me a while to realise, but when you see the divisions in the main tank, those divisions represent how much fuel it takes to fill the reservoir. If your configuration is such that the divisions are tiny, you no longer see them. TLDR- On some configurations a reservoir refill can seriously dent your main supply. Scooping *should* fill both imo, but FD disagree.